# SDWebImage load pictures and something about setting HTTP headers

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I'm facing the problem that every picture has different HTTP headers and I have to set it before downloading:

```
SDWebImageDownloader *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager].imageDownloader;
[manager @"value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"key];
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

But when I set many pictures, only the last picture can be loaded. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.imageDownloader.headersFilter

Comment: Think you for your answer ! I found another solution.But I don't know how reply it at comment,so I wrtie another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution from sdwebimage issue.

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.imageDownloader.headersFilter  = ^NSDictionary *(NSURL *url, NSDictionary *headers)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableHeaders = [headers mutableCopy];

    [mutableHeaders removeObjectForKey:@"your key"];

    [mutableHeaders setValue:@"your value" forKey:@"your key"];

    return mutableHeaders;
};
```

By this way,you can set differrent HTTP header for each image.

Comment: Right, you don't have the context though, only the URL.